# Colors for different priorities in Org mode

Tags: org-mode, faces

I have configured Org mode with a face attribute for priorities with these lines in my `init.el`:

```
(set-face-attribute 'org-priority nil
                    :foreground "aquamarine1"
                    :background "black"
                    :inherit font-lock-keyword-face
                    :inverse-video t
                    :box '(:line-width 2
                           :color "orange"
                           :style released-button))
```

But I'm wondering if there is a way to set different colors for priorities #A, #B & #C.

Answer (score 14):

You can customize `org-priority-faces` to give specific attributes for each priority.

---

From `C-h v org-priority-faces`,

> Documentation:
>   Faces for specific Priorities.
>   This is a list of cons cells, with priority character in the car
>   and faces in the cdr.  The face can be a symbol, a color as
>   as a string, or a property list of attributes, like
>       `(:foreground "blue" :weight bold :underline t)`.
>   If it is a color string, the variable `org-faces-easy-properties`
>   determines if it is a foreground or a background color.

**Edit:**

For example, this is my current setup:

```
'((65 :foreground "red" :background "yellow")
  (66 :foreground "black" :background "yellow")
  (67 . "blue"))
```

The numbers `65`, etc. correspond to the priority letters (ASCII 65 for `A`, etc.).

This is most easily configured using the `customize-variable` interface.

Comment: Any chance you could provide some example code, please?

Answer (score 7):

Here a example of customization

```el
(setq org-priority-faces '((?A . (:foreground "red" :weight 'bold))
                           (?B . (:foreground "yellow"))
                           (?C . (:foreground "green"))))
```

Comment: `bold` should not be quoted.

Comment: I was wondering what is the variable name to change the text itself of the priority entry, not the A, B or C. Any ideas? Thanks!